# what's the diff btw 'empty return' and 'return None'?

Tags: python

i was implementing merge sort and in the base case found that there is no diff btw empty return and return None.

```
if cond:
   return
```

and

```
if cond:
   return None
```

is there any diff or 2 are equivalent?

Comment: They are equivalent.  I tend to use an explicit `return None` if the function may return different types.

Comment: For the caller of the function - they are the same. But for anyone reading the code, it's a matter of explicit vs implicit.

Comment: There is also a difference in Python 2, if the function is a generator (i.e. has `yield` inside) - in that case `return` is a valid way to end the function whereas `return None` is not.

Comment: PEP recommends `return None` if any valid value is returned elsewhere in the function, otherwise `return` is fine.

Comment: "The `return` statement returns with a value from a function. `return` without an expression argument returns `None`. Falling off the end of a function also returns `None`." (from the [Official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement), if no expression is given to return then `None` is substituted. So no there is no difference.

Edit:

Even with no `return` statement, a function returns `None`:

```
>>> def f():
...    print("do nothing")
...
>>> r=f()
do nothing
>>> r is None
True
```